# Scrape upload date from YouTube Channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm looking to aggregate the upload dates from a user's YouTube channel onto a Google sheet. I can't make heads or tails of Google's API page. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: First you need to get all playlists for the given channelId.
Then you need to get all videos for that channel.
There you will find status.puplishedAt property which tells you what you need. Here you'll find details on how to do the api calls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953499/youtube-api-to-fetch-all-videos-on-a-channel or if you are using nodejs here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49117253/node-js-get-request-pagination-async/49119936#49119936

Comment: @baar is there any way to easily aggregate this information? I'm dealing with >100 videos and would prefer not to have to copy and paste the publishedAt prop for each one.

Comment: first you have to get all that informations then you can of course loop through the results and just save video id and publishedAt time. Does that answer your question ?

Comment: @baar let me take a bit to try to figure this out. This is my first time doing anything of this caliber.

Comment: @baar using the links your provided, I'm only able to get data for the last 50 videos posted on a channel, but the first channel I'm working with has around 90.

Comment: you need to use nextPageToken from the first request to do another. Until there is no nextPageToken anymore.

Comment: Check the second link again, in the answer i've posted there you can see how to do that. Look at `getPlaylist` function